# use sed to replace a line

Tags: unix, sed, substitution

I have been struggling to do this. I need to replace a line in a document with either blank space or the word "DELETED." The lines are different, and I am running a counter to determine the correct line to replace. So far, I have been using:

```
sed -ie ''$NUMLINE's/^$/DELETED/' Brown_Adam_CIVForms.txt
```

I would like to replace the NUMLINE-th line from this document (whatever it may be) and replace it with either blank space or the word "DELETED." Please help!!

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just insert `.*` between `^` and `$`. Like:

```
sed -ie $NUMLINE's/^.*$/DELETED/' Brown_Adam_CIVForms.txt
```

Comment: This was awesome. Worked perfectly. Thanks! Any advice for only changing the line if the previous line is not "--"? THANKS!!!

Comment: Whenever I need to work on more than one line, I switch from `sed` to `awk` or `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `awk`

```
awk -vnum=$NUMLINE 'NR==num{$0="DELETED"}1' file
```