# Bash: Using sed -i to replace a line with a $ variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am looking to replace an entire line in one .sh file with another .sh file using the `sed -i` command in bash.

The command pattern `sed <line number>s/<search pattern>/<replacement string>/` and I'm replacing the entire line with a replacement string that contains a `$` variable.

The first file `write.sh` contains the information that must be written to the second file `insert.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

output_file="/random/path/that/should/be/there1/"
error_file="/random/path/that/should/be/there2/"

sed -i '2s/.*/#SBATCH --job-name=775_none/' insert.sh
sed -i '3s/.*/#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1/' insert.sh
sed -i '4s/.*/#SBATCH --mem=5GB/' insert.sh
sed -i '5s/.*/#SBATCH --output="'$output_file'"/' insert.sh
sed -i '6s/.*/#SBATCH --error="'$error_file'"/' insert.sh
sed -i '7s/.*/#SBATCH --time=5:00:00/' insert.sh
```

All lines work except for lines 5s and 6s with the error returning:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unknown option to `s'
```

The second file `insert.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=none-chi-1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=5GB
#SBATCH --output=/path/i/want/to/repalce
#SBATCH --error=/path/i/want/to/repalce
#SBATCH --time=8:00:00
```

and what I would like is

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=775_none
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=5GB
#SBATCH --output=/random/path/that/should/be/there1/
#SBATCH --error=/random/path/that/should/be/there2/
#SBATCH --time=5:00:00
```

Some links I have checked:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060345/bash-replace-line-using-sed-and-2-variables),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618085/use-sed-to-replace-a-line),
[3](https://superuser.com/questions/1239822/using-sed-command-for-a-specific-line)

Any assistance would be appreciated if this is possible.

Comment: Can you show original content of `insert.sh` and your expected output

Comment: The immediate problem is that you can't use slashes as delimiters when your data contains unescaped slashes. More fundamentally, repeatedly running `sed -i` on the same file is inelegant, inefficient, and error-prone. Try `sed -i -e '2s/.*/#SBATCH --job-name=775_none/' -e '3s/.*/#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1/' -e '4s/.*/#SBATCH --mem=5GB/'` etc

Comment: Also, you want the strings to remain quoted, like `-e '5s%.*%#SBATCH --output="'"$output_file"'"%'` or just `"5s%.*%#SBATCH --output=\"$output_file\"%"`

Comment: Perhaps also review the [Stack Overflow `sed` tag info page](/tags/sed/info) which has links to common FAQs, including most of what was discussed here.